# Integrate django_agent_trust with django_two_factor_auth

Tags: django, django-authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have installed django_two_factor_auth successfully: token logins, backup tokens and SMS via Twilio all seem to work fine. My users will not tolerate having to enter their token for every login, though.

My needs are similar to those discussed in the following:
https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/issues/56

I wish to offer the user an option to defer OTP verification for 30 days after a successful verification.

To this end, I installed django_agent_trust. I patched AuthenticationTokenForm to add a BooleanField if django_agent_trust is installed:

(two_factor/forms.py, in AuthenticationTokenForm)

```
try:
    from django_agent_trust import trust_agent
    trust_this_agent = forms.BooleanField(label=_("Trust this browser for 30 days"),
                                          required=False)
except:
    pass
```

and I have been able to unconditionally set and reset the is_trusted flag by using django_agent_trust's django_agent_trust.trust_agent API.

The problem is figuring out where to capture the user's selected value of the BooleanField. I'm lost somewhere in the form wizard.

I would accept an answer questioning the wisdom of my overall approach if I think your argument makes sense. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

## in the beginning

*django_agent_trust* seemed like a good shortcut for this use case. It already had secure cookie support, a feature of Django I'd never used before, plus all the convenience methods I thought I'd need.

I was able to get it working with a little extra work.

## problem

The problem I ran into was that *django_agent_trust* validates the signed cookie only after the user is authenticated -- with an authenticated user from the request object. Since I was trying to minimize changes to *django_two_factor_auth*, I needed to decide whether or not to show the OTP form *before* authentication occurs.

## solution

All the tools I needed were in *django_agent_trust*. I pulled the methods I needed out of its middleware and into a new utils.py, adding a 'user' argument to *load_agent()*. Then I was able to check the cookie against the validated-but-not-yet-logged-in user object from *django_two_factor_auth*'s *LoginView* class.

Now *django_two_factor_auth*'s *LoginView* can test for agent trust in *has_token_step* and *has_backup_step*, and everything works [more or less as the author predicted 11 months ago](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/issues/56)...sigh.

I think adding this trust element might make sense as an enhancement to *django_two_factor_auth*. Juggling hacks to all these components seems like the wrong way to do it.

### later

I took a cue from the *django_otp* project and [added *agent_trust* as a "plugin" to *two_factor*](https://github.com/csghormley/django-two-factor-auth/tree/agent-trust/). It seems usable and maybe a little easier to digest in this form. This worked for me, but I suspect there's a much better way to do it. Patches welcome.